# Safari Disable Autocomplete Or any alternatives?

Tags: jquery

We use a jquery component called [JQuery Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/), to suggest the user postcodes based on the city they type in. It works fine, but on Safari the `autocomplete="off"` is not supported. One alternative is to pop up the suggestion on top of the input. But this solution it's out of the question. Does anyone know how to deaktivate this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer ist zu use `id` and `name` attributes, wich are not calling like "postcode", "zipcode", "zip" and so on. Change the values to for example "value1" and the popup disappears.